# XSD- How to check attribute is null and Special Characters defined in pattern

Tags: xml, xsd

My XSD as follows

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="AttNode">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="AttNodeChild"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="AttNodeGroup"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:attributeGroup name="AttNodeGroup">
    <xs:attribute ref="att" use="required"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
  <xs:attribute name="att" type="patternAtt" />
  <xs:simpleType name="patternAtt">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
      <xs:pattern value="(|[TT]|YY|UU)(,(|[TT]|YY|UU))"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD validation is working fine when below pattern in attribute value but I dont wont attribute values as null

```
<AttNode>
<AttNodeChild att="YY,UU"/>
</AttNode>
```

I tried to give Null check and String value with special character in Pattern but failed , Please post your suggestions

Failing validations

Case 01:

```
<AttNode>
    <AttNodeChild att="[TT],UU"/>
    </AttNode>
```

Case 02:

```
<AttNode>
<AttNodeChild att=""/>
        </AttNode>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get case 01 to validate by escaping `[` and `]`in regular expressions to `\[` and `\]` (they are special characters).

You can get case 02 to validate, i.e., accept the empty string, by adding a `?` after the closing parenthesis at the end.